# S3 Bucket Restrict Upload Mime Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket instance that I am writing to via a 3rd party comms tool.

[beefree.io](https://beefree.io/)

Sadly bee to do not provide the option to filter file upload types. As such, I would like to apply a policy to my bucket, so that essentially if it is not an image, I would not allow it.

I do not want to simply filter via file extension, as this can be spoofed, instead I was going to attempt `mime-type`.

This is my current attempt at a policy, however this is throwing an error as not valid JSON.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1533037015934",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1533037014139",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::com.xxxx.s3-bucket/*"
        }
    ],
    "Condition": [
        {
            "starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In condition mentioned wrong json. must have to specify key and it's associated value so correct it. Like {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1533037015934",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1533037014139",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::com.xxxx.s3-bucket/*"
    }
  ],
  "Condition": [
    {
      "mime-type": "starts-with"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I get ```Invalid bucket policy syntax.```

Comment: Can you please check with this revised policy. {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1533037015934",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1533037014139",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::com.xxxx.s3-bucket/*"
    }
  ],
  "Condition": [
    [
      "starts-with",
      "$Content-Type",
      "image/"
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: I'm afraid this returns invalid json

Comment: Remove the dollar sign from $Content-Type